# Circular dependency found in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

Tring to add interceptor header for my every request, however, it is giving me below error.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- Auth <- httpRequestInterceptor <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $route

app.js

```
var app= angular.module('myDemoApp',['ngRoute'])


app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['Auth', function (Auth) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {

      config.headers['x-access-token'] = Auth.getToken();
      return config;
    }
  };
}]);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

Auth Service

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    myDemoApp.factory('Auth', ['$http', '$window', Auth]);

    /******Auth function start*****/
    function Auth($http, $window) {
        var authFactory = {};

        authFactory.setToken = setToken;
        authFactory.getToken = getToken;
        return authFactory;


        /*setToken function start*/
        function setToken(token) {

            if (token) {
                $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            } else {
                $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
            }

        }

        /*getToken function start*/
        function getToken() {
            return $window.localStorage.getItem('token')
        }

    }


})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this because.

1. You have created `httpRequestInterceptor` which intercepts all `$http` requests.
2. Now, you are passing `Auth` in the `httpRequestInterceptor`.
3. If you'll see, `Auth` uses `$http` request inside itself.
4. So, your `interceptor` can itself cause a `http` request using `Auth`.

Hence, its circular error and `angularjs` wont allow you to do that !

Remove `$http` from `Auth` factory **OR** dont insert a service into interceptor which itself uses `$http`.

I hope you got, how the infinite loop chain being created, hence a `circular dependency` error !

Comment: Thanks. I have remove $http service and it is working fine now.